# Can we conclude $f$ is analytic inside $C$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be **continuous** on and inside a simple closed contour $C$ such that $\int_Cf(z)dz=0.$ Can we conclude $f$ is analytic inside $C?$

Comment: ?? You are assuming it's analytic inside $C$, and you're asking whether it's analytic inside $C$?

Comment: If $f$ is analytic on and inside $C$, it is analytic inside $C$. You probably meant : "Can we conclude $f=0$ inside $C$?"

Comment: I suspect that girianshiido's guess is not what Sriti meant, because almost any analytic $f$ would be a counterexample (e.g., $f(z)=1$).  My guess at the meaning, though, is even further from what Shriti wrote: Don't assume analyticity, and try to prove it from the assumption that the integral vanishes over *all* simple closed contours in the domain.

Comment: @Carl, your one-size-fits-all comment doesn't fit when the real problem with the question is that the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: yes, I realized only after posting it that the question is not only badly written in terms of context and motivation, but also phrased in a way that makes it trivial. I deleted the old comment for now. However, when the question is edited to make it match the intent of the asker, I do think that additional context, and a description of what has been tried, should also be added.

Comment: Sorry. Edited..

Comment: An easy counterexample to the updated problem seems to be $C = \{e^{\theta\pi i}|\theta\in[0,2\pi]\}$ and $f\colon z\mapsto 1-|z|$.

Comment: I think $f(z)=x$ is another simple counterexample ($C$ being the unit circle).

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, there are simple counterexamples, e.g., with $C$ the unit circle, one can take $f(z)=1-|z|$, or $f(z)=f(x+iy)=x$, or $f(z)=\overline z$.